# timeout for std::sync::semaphore

Tags: multithreading, rust, semaphore

I have an `std::sync::Semaphore`

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    lock: std::sync::Semaphore
}
```

There is a thread that calls `release` on the semaphore at some interval to indicate that new items are available in a queue.

Meanwhile, to process items, I want to acquire the semaphore:

```
myStruct.lock.acquire();
```

But in the case that the acquisition takes a long time, I want to do something else, like return an error code rather than wait for the resource indefinitely.  But this call blocks forever.

How do I set a timeout so that I only wait on the semaphore for a finite amount of time?

Comment: Would a [`Condvar`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) suit your case?

Comment: As I understand it, in the case that nobody is waiting, calling Condvar.notify_one() has no effect, while Semaphore.release() will increase the semaphore.  In the case that a thread comes along and waits after the notification is sent, the behavior is different.

Comment: A `Mutex` plus a `Condvar` could satisfy this use case, in fact, that is how `Semaphore` itself is implemented. Copying the `Semaphore` code and adding an `acquire_with_timeout` wouldn't be too hard.